# GUI and C coding gtk files?

Tags: gtk, gui, c

I am trying to write a program in C and I need the gtk/gtk.h file, which I both currently don't appear to have nor am I sure how to get it.

When I compile all I get is cannot find the file, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

search the newest libgtk-dev file in the [debian package repository](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) and download it.

gtk.h should be in the package.

Comment: ok. so search the newest libgtk-dev file in the debian package repository and download it. gtk.h should be in the package.

Comment: please edit your answer and add details there inorder to be voted up or accepted

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to code using gtk I would suggest you start by looking [here](http://developer.gnome.org/) for tutorials. I would really suggest you use vala or python for any gui work though, c is not really the best choice for this task.

As to the files you need. They are contained within the `libgtk-3-dev` package which can be installed with `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`.